# Can't find iOS crash reports

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, logging, crash

The only crash logs I have on my iPhone are from last November, but I know my (debug, non-released) app has crashed a million times since then. What determines if a crash goes to the Diagnostics and Usage info? I've tried looking in the Devices window of Xcode. Same logs as on iPhone.

I just want to find stack traces for the app I am debugging. That would be so helpful. How should I do it?

I'm on iOS 10.2.1

Comment: Why not run the app through Xcode and debug the crash directly?

Comment: And what version of iOS? Logs are in a different place in the Settings app in iOS 10.3.

Comment: Well rmaddy, I do debug it that way, but I also test the app a lot on the go. It would be nice if it were possible to go through those crash logs. I'm adding the iOS version to my post.

Comment: It's possible to get the crash logs through `Window > Devices > View Device Logs`

Comment: Zonily Jame, Yes I have checked there, but there are only crash logs from November of last year. No new ones. I can't figure out why, or how to fix it.